# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘pyzed’

Tags: ros, ros-noetic

when editing the program in the ros environment，it shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/home/young/my_yolo/src/yolov7-ros/src/detect_ros.py”, line 24, in
import pyzed.sl as sl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘pyzed’
```

Please tell me how to configurein ros environment so that we can use the import pyzed.sl as sl module . thank you.
import pyzed.sl
it can be used successfully in my python environment，but can not used in ros environment，I wonder if we should configure the environment in cmakelist.txt

Comment: How did you install pyzed?  get_python_api.py as in https://www.stereolabs.com/docs/app-development/python/install ?